# Как узнать значение переменной другого сайта?

Tags: php, html

Всем привет.

Откровенно, я мало что понимаю в php, но очень надеюсь, что подскажете, в каком направлении хотя бы гуглить.

Есть сайт, на нем товар. Если открыть код страницы, то есть такие данные (см. скрин),
меня интересует в данный момент одно число: data-price. Т.е. надо запрос на моей страничке, который обратиться к этому сайту и выведет мне число (в данном случае 0.0013).

Заранее благодарю. =)

[image]

Comment: @maffy27, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо распарсить страницу. Для этого есть несколько способов:

1. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php - стандартная либа PHP.
2. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm - удобная либа для парсинга.
       Вот гайд по ней:
       http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/72702/

Answer (score 1):

```
$html= file_get_contents("http://shop.ru/"); 
preg_match_all('/data-price=\"(.*)\"/i',$html,$price);
print_r($price); # <= Результат
```

Answer (score 0):

html можно распарсить как xml. Хотя это гарантируется только для xhtml ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)).

Библиотеки для парсинга xml можно найти.

Можно самому по тексту пройтись и найти подстроку "data-price", но это если гарантируется, что нигде больше, кроме как переменная, эта строка не встретится.